# Triggering an action on multiple devices at the same time

Tags: android, networking, websocket, synchronization, udp

I'm trying to trigger an action inside my Android app on multiple devices at the exact same time (or with the lowest delay/shift possible).

The devices are strictly similar (brand, model, version), plugged via USB to a Macbook Pro. I have 4 devices so far but the final solution will include many more so I need a solution that works with a lot of devices.

I have tried using sockets (Socket.io and regular WS) over Wifi and USB, but the delay slightly increases for each device so the action is not triggered in sync.

I also tried sending a broadcast UDP packet over USB, this gives way better results but seems very inconsistent: the max delay goes from 10 to a 100ms.

Syncing clocks was another option I was considering but not sure how accurate can it get across many devices (and NTP seems tricky on Android)

Any idea or pattern to address this kind of requirements? Thanks!

**EDIT**

So after doing some tests, the most accurate option was to sync the devices clocks using NTP as suggested by Sam Mason (I'm using [this library](https://github.com/medavox/MuTime)). I managed to get an average 5ms shift between my 4 devices.

Comment: That sounds like a job for multicast, but remember that broadcast and multicast are problematic for Wi-Fi because it must be sent at the lowest speed so that even distant clients can receive it. Some WAPs are configured to change that to individual unicasts and will send them serially. On a wired network, or Wi-Fi not configured to change broadcast/multicast to unicast, every host will simultaneously receive the packet. Differences can arise because of latency inside the receiving hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first some observations:

1. mobile devices tend to power down NICs aggressively to conserve power (I'm not sure how much this is affected by whether they are currently charging)
2. they also throttle their CPU frequency if they're not being used and it can take a while (i.e. milliseconds) to get them back up to speed.  given that your devices are all the "same" the variance in your measurements would probably be dominated by other apps also running
3. measuring the delay in apps responding seems non-trivial, doing this via a network might increase variance because all devices are contesting each other (note that USB is a "serial bus" so this applies here as well).  depending on how much this matters it might be worth setting up a video camera and watch their screens

that said, I'd be tempted to rely on their clocks to do this.  NTP sync can be great (e.g. sub-millisecond precision is pretty easy) but probably not for mobile devices (I'd assume Android NTP clients care more about power and anything less than a few seconds is fine for humans).  that said, their clocks should be pretty stable, so have your clients check in (randomly so there's less network contention, and do it a few times so the NIC is properly powered up).  the clients can use this to figure out how long until the "event", then sleep until a few milliseconds before this.  they can then wake up and do a busy loop checking the time (to make sure the CPU is powered up) and then continue at the appropriate time

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, I will definitely give a try to the clock/NTP approach and report back.
So far my method to measure delay was to point all devices to another phone displaying a timer and triggering each device's camera to get a "visual timestamp".
The camera (via the API) is set to manual to disable all the default auto adjustment routines and the shutter speed increased to a high value. I'm wondering if this approach also introduces a random delay that could give wrong results.

Comment: screens normally update at 60hz, while the latency in setting up and taking a full-sensor picture is going to be much more than 17ms.  taking a high frame rate video might do better, but there will also be buffering/unpredictable latency involved so unless the hardware is timestamping frames (apparently some does this) I'd assume the display is more predictable.  note that android buffers screen updates (not sure if it's double or triple) but this should be a fixed delay hence you might be able to measure this within +-8ms.  https://danluu.com/input-lag/ might be interesting reading